# Name Badge Date Format

Tags: civievent, localisation, pdf, dates

In CiviCrm 4.7 Drupal I created a new Name Badge Layout which includes Event End Date. The site language is Italian, so I need the date to be printed as "15 Ottobre 2016", but it comes out as "Ottobre 15th", which does not make any sense.

Where can I change this setting? I looked everywhere but it seems to be hardcoded somewhere and I can't it.

Many thanks.

Comment: There are date settings here: civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?reset=1

Comment: I know that, but those settings seem to have no effect at all on the way the date is printed on the badge, which is a format that does not exist in any of my settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it.

In CRM/Badge/BAO/Badge.php around line 101 it says:

```
// hack to fix date field display format
if (strpos($element, '_date')) {
  $value = CRM_Utils_Date::customFormat($value, "%B %E%f");
}
```

So I just re-hacked the hack and replaced "%B %E%f" with "%e %B %Y".